# Difficulty removing class on .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Situation:** I have created a nav with a click function that allows the sub nav to `.slideToggle();` when user clicks the nav link.

**Issue:** The active class is added to the nav link when clicked but does not remove itself when the user clicks on a sibling nav link. It continues to add active classes one by one.

**Questions:** How can I properly write the function to add the class to the clicked link, then remove the class when a sibling link is clicked while adding the class to the now selected link, etc...

**JS Code:**

```
// Pillar side navigation function
$('.side-nav-link').click(function(e) {
  var $pillarNav = $('.pillar-subnav')

  $(this).removeClass('side-nav-active');

  if ($pillarNav.is(':visible')) {
    $pillarNav.slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
  } else {
    $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
  }

  $(this).addClass('side-nav-active');

  e.preventDefault()
});
```

Here is the working **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/o7ojbxn8/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the class from all elements that have that class, then add it to the current, here's a cleaner way to do it

```js
$('.side-nav-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  var $pillarNav = $('.pillar-subnav')
  var $subnav = $(this).next('.pillar-subnav').stop().slideToggle();
  var $this = $(this).toggleClass('side-nav-active');

  $('.side-nav-link').not($this).removeClass('side-nav-active');
  $pillarNav.not($subnav).slideUp();
});
```

```css
.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.pillar-links>li {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: solid 1px #e3e3e3;
  padding: 5px;
}

.pillar-nav>.side-nav-item>.side-nav-link,
.nav>.side-nav-item>.nav-link {
  color: #555555;
  padding: 15px;
}

.pillar-subnav {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.pillar-subnav li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.pillar-subnav li a {
  color: #555555;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pillar-subnav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #006a65;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.side-heading {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9dc4c3;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.side-nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #6e9da3;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.side-nav-item {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.side-nav-item::after {
  content: "4";
  font-family: "webdings", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.side-nav-item:last-child::after {
  top: 17px;
}

.side-nav-item:last-child,
.pillar-subnav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.side-nav-item .side-nav-link:hover,
.side-nav-active,
.side-nav-item .nav-link:hover,
.pillar-links>li:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-left: 4px solid #006a65;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="side-nav">
  <nav>
    <div class="side-heading">
      <h4>Communication Platform</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav pillar-nav">
      <li class="side-nav-item">
        <a class="side-nav-link" href="#">CSL Behring Transplant Franchise</a>
        <ul class="pillar-subnav">
          <li><a href="#">Transplant Franchise Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Solid Organ Transplantation Overview</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="side-nav-item">
        <a class="side-nav-link" href="#">Organ Availability and Patient/Donor Matching</a>
        <ul class="pillar-subnav">
          <li><a href="#">Organ Donation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Matching Organs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Desensitization</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="side-nav-item">
        <a class="side-nav-link" href="#">Organ Viability and Donor Management</a>
        <ul class="pillar-subnav">
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="side-nav-item">
        <a class="side-nav-link" href="#">Ischemia-Reperfusion Injury (IRI)</a>
        <ul class="pillar-subnav">
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="side-nav-item">
        <a class="side-nav-link" href="#">Transplant Rejection</a>
        <ul class="pillar-subnav">
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pillar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: @adeneo That's interesting. I thought you had to call the element with the class to remove the class but in that line you call the class to remove it, if that makes sense. In the past I have called the `li` and removed the class but it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `not()` and `toggleClass()`

```
$('.side-nav-link').not($(this)).removeClass('side-nav-active');
$(this).toggleClass('side-nav-active');
```

[***Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/o7ojbxn8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove active from everything first, then apply to `$(this)` only

```
// Pillar side navigation function
$('.side-nav-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var $pillarNav = $('.pillar-subnav')
  $('.side-nav-link').removeClass('side-nav-active');

  $(this).addClass('side-nav-active');

  if ($pillarNav.is(':visible')) {
    $pillarNav.slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
  } else {
    $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and readable one :)

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fsc1vc9b/2/)***

```
// Pillar side navigation function
var $allLinks = $('.side-nav-link');
var $allSubnav = $(".pillar-subnav");

$allLinks.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault()

  // LINKS
  $allLinks.not(this).removeClass("side-nav-active"); // All
  $(this).toggleClass("side-nav-active");             // Clicked link

  // SUBNAVS
  var $mySubnav = $(this).closest("li").find(".pillar-subnav");
  $allSubnav.not($mySubnav).stop().slideUp();         // All
  $mySubnav.stop().slideToggle();                     // Related subnav

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, toggle class for $(this) and remove the siblings:

`$(this).toggleClass('side-nav-active').siblings().removeClass('side-nav-active');`